# Authentifying a call to a smart contract function

Tags: authentication

I'm writing a play-to-earn game that rewards players with tokens. Each time, the player completes a "round" and collects a certain number of points, he is eligible to claim a corresponding number of tokens. To claim those tokens, the players simply clicks a button, signs a transaction via metamask which calls a public function in the smart contract (SC) (which calls the ERC20 _mint function).

However, as the function is public, anyone can simply replace the UI (the actual game) with his frontend code and call the public SC function in order to mint any amount of tokens he desires.

What is the best approach to deal with that kind of scenario? How can I make sure that only players who earn points can mint a corresponding number of tokens? Generate an encrypted password on the frontend that will be checked on the SC...?

Comment: The kind of password trick you're thinking about is cryptographically impossible. People can (and will) cheat by creating their own frontends to your contract, so your contract has to enforce that they follow the rules of the game or your game is impossible to implement on the blockchain.

Comment: From the description it seems the contract is only used to accumulate the points. In that case it is just a regular game that uses the blockchain to accumulate points, so you could use a backend to keep users stats and sign messages for minting tokens.